# "Incompatible types when assigning to type" when inserting NULL into array of structs

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm trying to implement chaining (hash) in C. I've written the following code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define size 10

typedef struct hashNode
{
    int data;
    struct hashNode *next;
} node;

int main()
{
    node chain[size];
    
    for(int i=0; i<=(size-1); i++)
        chain[i] = NULL;
    
    //insert(chain, 10);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:31,
                 from chaining.c:2:
chaining.c: In function ‘main’:
chaining.c:33:14: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘node’ {aka ‘struct hashNode’} from type ‘void *’
   33 |   chain[i] = NULL;
      |              ^~~~
```

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer. `chain[i]` is a node, not a pointer to a node.

Comment: Maybe you meant `node *chain[size]`?

Comment: `chain[i].next = NULL;` maybe? If so, you could skip the loop and just initialize the array directly with `node chain[size] = {0};`

Comment: `chain` is an inappropriate name. This is an **array** of elements, not at _chain_. (Perhaps you could use `chains` to indicate that each used element of the array is at one end of a _link list_ of nodes (aka "chain").

Comment: BTW instead of writing `i<=(size-1)` it's idiomatic to write `i < size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is normally used to indicate that a pointer is not pointing to any valid memory location. Chain is an array of node **objects** and *not* an array of *pointers* to node objects hence you must set a pointer.

```
node *chain[size];
```

I, also, see that you are looping through size - 1 which is redundant and would lead to unexpected behaviour within unsigned datatypes. You can simply go by `i < size`

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    chain[i] = NULL;
```

Edit: Thanks [@fe2o3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17592432/fe2o3) for pointing out that using the loop to set all elements to `NULL` is old-school and I fully agree.

There are other methods to employ such as using `memset`, `calloc` or `designated initialization` with newer compilers.

Using `memset`:

```
memset(chain, 0, sizeof(chain));
```

Using `designated inits`: Docs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

```
node* chain[SIZE] = { [0 ... SIZE - 1] = NULL };
```

Lastly, using `calloc`:  Although, ensure to free the allocated mems when you're done.

```
node** chain = (node**)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(node*));
//Free when you're done...
free(chain);
```

Comment: UV because, as you've indicated, the **array** _should_ be pointers to nodes, not an array of ("hash") nodes... Initialising all elements to NULL using a loop is _old school_ and could be improved.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thanks, I edited the answer based on your suggestion and yes, it's important to state that there are better ways to initialize elements to NULL than a mere for loop...

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're trying to make all the `node`s point at `NULL` initially, but the `node`s aren't pointers. They have a pointer member called `next` though, so what you should be doing is:

```c
for(int i=0; i<=(size-1); i++)
    chain[i].next = NULL;
```

You could also skip the loop and initialize the array directly upon defining it:

```c
node chain[size] = {0};
```

---

Sidenote: Do not write `i<=(size-1)`. It has an extraneous cognitive load and wouldn't be safe in situations where `size` is of an `unsigned` type (which is common). Write `i < size`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    node chain[size];
    
    for(int i=0; i<=(size-1); i++)
        chain[i] = NULL;
```

1. `i<=(size-1)` => `i < size`
2. `chain[i]` is a struct, not a pointer and you cant assign NULL to it.

- You can use compound literal instead:

```
chain[i] = (node){0};
```

- you can use `memset`

```
memset(&chain[i], 0, sizeof(chain[i]));
```

- or if it is just an initialization:

```
node chain[size] = {0,};
```